# Best way to remove illegal characters from url / filename / foldername?

Tags: 2007

What is the best way to remove illegal characters from sharepoint(MOSS) filenames, foldernames, urls, etc...

Basic character removal process is not enough...

Thanks in advance
SAV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SPEncode class to do what you want.

Your choices are :

```
SPEncode.HtmlEncode(string);
SPEncode.HtmlEncodePreserveSpaces(string);
```

Good luck !

See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spencode_methods.aspx

Comment: That doesn`t remove common illegal characters which SharePoint cant eat example [ ~ # % & * { } \ : < > ? / + | " . _  ]

Comment: RegularExpression is useful for that but...I think there is no built in method for that in SP API

Comment: http://geek.hubkey.com/2008/11/get-valid-sharepoint-file-or-folder.html

Comment: Found answer and method snippet exampl about the whole thing... http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2010/06/17/how-to-generate-a-valid-sharepoint-filename/ Great example and blog post about it

Comment: It is useful for files and folders.  Bu you should keep the Encode methode for the URL ! Thanks for the links, they are interesting !